# Strip formatting with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Simple question - after much Googling no real answer.

I want tinyMCE to stop auto-formatting text when it is pasted in. When text is copied and pasted in the text editor I want the text to be just text. None of the fluff which tinyMCE add's.

I don't need 'paste from word', I don't need anything else. I JUST WANT PLAIN TEXT PASTE EVERY TIME.

Surely there is an option to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not an option to do this here and if then it is not reliable.
I use the paste_preprocessing parameter to get plain text. Everything is decribed here:
[TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)