# Stripping styles from TinyMCE copy+paste?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

is there a way to strip specific tags from coming into tiny MCE through a copy+paste from an external source (e.g. Word)?  I'd like to prevent font-family and image tags from being copy+pasted over, but have no problem with font-size etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question uses a bit confusing wording. If I understand it right, you want to remove specific *inline styles* (eg. `font-family`) and *tags* (eg. `<img>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really stop someone from pasting something, so I believe your best bet would be to filter out the unwanted tags by calling a function on form submit, or onchange of the tiny MCE textarea. Then you could use some regular expression replacement to get rid of the unwanted tags.

**EDIT:** Actually there is a simple way. check the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#invalid_elements).

Comment: I understand that, I want to allow copy paste I just want to strip certain elements of the copy paste (certain tags in the span that comes from word or a website).  I was hoping TinyMCE might support that in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry I couldn't find that, scanned the documentation but must have missed it.

Comment: `invalid_elements`, `valid_styles` and `invalid_styles` seem relevant, but doesn't seem to work on pasting :/

Comment: `valid_elements` did not appear to work for me with a CTRL-V paste, but did apply if I pressed a TinyMCE button like "align_center". A paragraph appeared centered in TinyMCE but in the resulting output it was not centered because I'd removed p[styles] from `valid_elements` and I guess TinyMCE would add an inline style to do the centering in the output. Tested with TinyMCE 6 in Umbraco 11.
TinyMCE docs state that `invalid_elements` is for elements only and not their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to a similar SO question with a detailed description of howto strip out unwanted tags: [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how useful this will be, but you might want to take a look at this jQuery plugin which allows you to filter tags and attributed from the text your are pasting.

[FilteredPaste.js - A jQuery Plugin To Filter & Clean Pasted Input](http://willemmulder.github.io/FilteredPaste.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Although "You can't really stop someone from pasting something" indeed, you *can transform* what your web app inserts into your TinyMCE textbox (or any other input).

1. Listen to the browser's native [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) event.
2. Parse the clipboard's `text/html` string with [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
3. Make changes in the generated DOM tree.
4. Set the textbox content to the stripped content.
5. Prevent the `paste` default action.

Check this out:

```js
editor.on ('paste', event => {

  // Get clipboard's original HTML string
  const clipboard = event.clipboardData
  const originalHtml = clipboard.getData ('text/html')

  // Parse HTML string into a DOMElement
  const parser = new DOMParser
  const doc = parser.parseFromString (originalHtml, 'text/html')

  // Modify DOM tree
  const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll ('*')
  elems.forEach (elem => {
    elem.style.fontFamily = ''
    // Do other modifications here...
  })

  // Set textbox content to modified HTML
  editor.setContent (doc.body.innerHTML)

  // Prevent pasting original content
  event.preventDefault ()
})
```