# Copy text (plain-text) from tinymce to textarea

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

Not sure if any of you have done this or not, but wanted to put some feelers out there.

I have a TinyMce editor (in an MVC3 view) which a user can basically create an email "template" in.  In addition, I have another textarea without TinyMce.

I want to be able to copy the plain text from the TinyMce to the textarea (it will be the "plain-text" version of the email).  I've seen some js to strip out the code, but I'd like to take the links ( tags) and copy the URLs out as well.

Let me know if you have any questions!  I greatly appreciate any help you may be able to give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to get the content first, strip out some of the contents, and then put it in your textarea. This is not that difficult:

1. `var content = tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getContent({format : 'raw', no_events : 1});`
2. Use the function strip_tags descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text) to strip out unwanted tags

`// keep p,div and br tags in this example`
`content = strip_tags( content,'<p><div><br>');`

3. `document.getElementsById('my_textarea').innerHTML = content;`

Comment: Copying the text is for the most part easy.  But getting it pulled out so it's "usable" (which I realize is a relative term) is different.

I also need to be able to take the value from the href of A tags and put the URL in the plain text

Comment: what do you mean with "usable"?

Comment: I did a variation of this.  I'll try to post the code once I clean it up and do some more testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose $("#TinyMceContainer").text() works?