# tinymce "paste from word" not stripping Calibri

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, tinymce

Using tinymce in wordpress 3.3.2 the paste from word function works great for my users, but I have run into one issue, whenever someone pastes content from a word document that is set in Calibri, Calibri remains, all other fonts strip out.

Anyone ever experience this or have an idea what may cause this?

Comment: If you want it to strip all formatting, use the paste as plain text option. Pasting from word should retain the formatting - so Calibri should be retained, but the other font should be as well. What are the other fonts that are getting stripped out?

Comment: The reason I liked paste from word was my users didn't have to recreate the links that are often in their documents. I tried a whole variety of fonts, some of the bigger names were arial, georgia, comic sans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of help to you: [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

You may want to fiddle a bit with the code to keep special tags or attributes.