# Remove HTML tags from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
var content = "<p>Dear sms,</p><p>This is a test notification for push message from center II.</p>";
```

and I want to remove all `<p>` and `</p>` tags from the above string. Just want to display the string values without html tags like  :

```
"Dear sms, This is a test notification for push message from center II."
```

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate. because it is tagged under Javascript too.

Comment: I holding that html string in a javascript varibale. I want to remove those tags from that variable

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Why not just let jQuery do it?

```
var content = "<p>Dear sms,</p><p>This is a test notification for push message from center II.</p>";

var text = $(content).text();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if `content` has something like &lt;div&gt; it will become a tag after this code is run

Comment: This does not remove a  `<br/>`

Comment: @PHPMaster5000: Yes it does. What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 32):

Here is  my solution ,

```
function removeTags(){
    var txt = document.getElementById('myString').value;
    var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    alert(txt.replace(rex , ""));

}
```

Comment: thanks man, this is the best answer, because its pure javascript and your regexp handles all the html tags

Comment: An improvement to this regex would be:
    (<([^>]+)>)|(&lt;([^>]+)&gt;)

This will remove standard html tags as well as any escaped tags.

Comment: Please don't process HTML using regular expressions. It is a mistake and you will likely get burned badly for it. HTML is not a regular language and a regular expression, even one thousands of characters long, is not sufficient for it. You need a real parser, or utilize functions of the browser/DOM.

I as an attacker could easily get HTML past both of these examples.

Comment: regex to remove &nbsp as well ?

Answer (score 9):

Using plain javascript :

```
content = content.replace(/(<p>|<\/p>)/g, "");
```

Comment: What about whitespace and/or attributes? For example `<p class="bla"></p >`

Comment: Answers the OP exact question, but if the tags have attributes the regex would need to be `/(<p[^>]*>|<\/p>)/g`

Comment: Here, the variable seems to be generated and I think it is easy to know which elements we have to remove... Even, if it is a bit more complicated, I think that this method will work : it is a basis on the question asked and can be easily adapted after.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get plain text `without` html tags.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VgHr3/)**

```
withoutP = $(content).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = "a<br />";
var withoutP = $(content).text()
alert(withoutP )
```

This one does not work for the .text() solution.

Answer (score 1):

this one is checking for special chars

```js
var $string = '&lt;a href=&quot;link&quot;&gt;aaa&lt;/a&gt;';
var $string2 = '<a href="link">aaa</a>';
var $string3 = 'BBBBB';
var $string4 = 'partial<script';
var $string5 = 'has    spaces';

function StripTags(string) {

  var decoded_string = $("<div/>").html(string).text();
  return $("<div/>").html(decoded_string).text();

}

console.log(StripTags($string));
console.log(StripTags($string2));
console.log(StripTags($string3));
console.log(StripTags($string4));
console.log(StripTags($string5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`myString.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');`

Answer (score 0):

Place `hidden element` in markup, or create it from jQuery. Use this code to get plain text without complications with incomplete tags, `&lt;` etc.

```
content = $(hiddenElement).html($(hiddenElement).html(content).text()).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above approch is not working for me. so i got one alternative solution to solve this issue`

```
var regex = "/<(.|\n)*?>/";
var originaltext = "1. Males and females were compared in terms of time    management ability. <br><br>The independent variables were the people in the   study.<br><br> Is this statement correct";
var resultText = body.replace(regex, "");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

`var cleanContent = content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags) module to remove HTML and get the text. It's quite an easy and straightforward solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
function htmlTagremove(text) {

   var cont = document.createElement('div'),
   cont.innerHTML=text;

   return $(cont).text();

}

htmlTagremove('<p><html>test');
```