# Replace numbers in String Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know that there are tons of similar questions, but this one may be slightly different.

I've got a series of `span` tags that each include unique Ids, which are all part of a JSON string. I am then trying to replace all of the Ids with empty strings, knowing that they contain numbers that are dynamic. For example, consider the following array of JSON objects `dataArray`

```
[
    {
        "name": "testOne",
        "tag": "<span id=my-test-1>Test One</span>"
    },
    {
        "name": "testTwo",
        "tag": "Test Two"
    },
    {
        "name": "testThree",
        "tag": "Test Three"
    },
    {
        "name": "testFour",
        "tag": "<span id=my-test-2>Test Four</span>"
    }
]
```

As you can see, some tags contain ids, and some do not. I am therefore looking to replace any `span` tags with empty strings (i.e. remove them) but as you can see, the numbers differ. It is also important to note that sometimes there may be more Ids that exist.

So far, I've got this:

```
const dataString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
const newData = data.replaceAll("<span id=my-test-??>", "") //First, remove the opening tags

JSON.parse(newData.replaceAll("</span>", "")) //then remove the closing tags
```

However, this won't replace all the tags that have a number in the `my-test-` Id. How can I therefore replace similar to the above but specify that an id can have any number that follows `my-test-`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove HTML tags from a javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911681/remove-html-tags-from-a-javascript-string)

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not looking to do it in Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dataString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);    
const regex = /<span.*?>|<\/span>/gm;
const newData = dataString.replace(regex,'');

JSON.parse(newData);
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. Could you explain what the regex is doing? Is the `.*?` matching any string that is contained? And what is the `/gm` reference?

Comment: g means its global (doesn't stop after the first match), m means its multiline.  The point matches everything.
*? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible.

Comment: The | means OR, the \ before / is to escape that character. https://regex101.com is a good ressource to test your regular expression and learn more about them.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array and replace the content inner the arrow. Like that:

```js
arr = [
    {
        "name": "testOne",
        "tag": "<span id=my-test-1>Test One</span>"
    },
    {
        "name": "testTwo",
        "tag": "Test Two"
    },
    {
        "name": "testThree",
        "tag": "Test Three"
    },
    {
        "name": "testFour",
        "tag": "<span id=my-test-2>Test Four</span>"
    }
]



n = arr.map(a => {
  a.tag = a.tag.replace(/>.*</g, "><");
  return a;
})

console.log(n)
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem with this (which I should've specified) is that this is just an example JSON. There could be different properties with different key value pairs that also include `span` tags.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
const dataToString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);    
const regex = /"<span([^]*)</span>"/gm;
const newData = dataString.replace(regex,"");

JSON.parse(newData);
```

when I put this code `([^]*)` between the span tags it matches any character

Comment: Thank you. This also works but I've simply accepted the other answer because it came first.

Comment: Sure, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe function like this is a solution for you:

```js
function replace(myString, start, end) {
  const beginning = myString.indexOf(start)
  const ending = myString.indexOf(end)
  return myString.slice(0, beginning) + myString.slice(ending+end.length, myString.length);
  
}

console.log(replace("I have my BigString and it's awesome!", "Big", "ing"))
```

it will remove everything between the substrings