# django-tinymce HTMLField - paste as plain text in admin

Tags: django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I've got django-tinymce installed and various models in my app with an `HTMLField`.

I'm trying to produce some sort of 'paste as plain text' functionality in the django admin. I want formatting from MS Word, HTML tags, and pretty much anything else stripped out when users do ctrl + v / cmd + v / right click > paste etc.

I can see lots of people talking about it but I can't seem to get anything to work. Being django-tinymce, I'm doing all of this in `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` in `settings.py`.

I thought I had it working - I'd overridden the base admin template to include a js file with the following function (I can't remember who to credit for the function - probably someone on SO)-

```
function tinymcePastePlainText() {
    var ed = tinyMCE.get(0);

    ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;  

    //adding handlers crossbrowser
    if (tinymce.isOpera || /Firefox\/2/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        ed.onKeyDown.add(function (ed, e) {
            if (((tinymce.isMac ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey) && e.keyCode == 86) || (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45))
                ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
        });
    } else {            
        ed.onPaste.addToTop(function (ed, e) {
            ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Then set up my default config -

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

'plugins': "'paste'",

'paste_text_sticky': "true",
'paste_retain_style_properties': "",
'oninit': "tinymcePastePlainText",

#...Further config

}
```

This seemed to be doing what I wanted last time I looked, but it's stopped working now - debugging in the browser seems to show that the `tinymcePastePlainText()` function is never run (though it is loaded).

I've tried various other methods such as simply setting my config to -

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

'plugins': "'paste'",

'paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste': 'true',
'paste_remove_styles': 'true',
'paste_remove_styles_if_webkit': 'true',
'paste_strip_class_attributes': 'true',

#....further config

}
```

(that didn't seem to change anything). Or

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

'plugins': "'paste'",

'setup': "function(ed) { ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;});",

#....further config

}
```

I've tried loading the above function from a seperate js file then including the function name in my config - `'setup': 'pasteAsPlainTextFuncion()'` but that didn't work either.

I seem to have spent ages on this, and I'm not really making any progress - I've no idea why my function was being called, and now it's not - the browser's debugging tool isn't picking up any errors.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I've included your link in my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infuriating! - For some reason I'd applied both single and double quotes on the the line - `'plugins': "'paste'",`. The paste plugin wasn't being loaded. I don't know how, why or when I did that.

For anyone else trying to do the same thing (I'm using django 1.4.3 and django-tinymce 1.5.1b2). I managed to get some basic 'paste as plain text' functionality (as default) without the use of a javascript callback anywhere. I simply used the following setup -

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

'plugins': "paste",

'paste_remove_styles': 'true',
'paste_remove_styles_if_webkit': 'true',
'paste_strip_class_attributes': 'all',

#... further config

}
```

I found the [paste plugin documentation](http://tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste) and [Thariama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text) on SO both very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a clear approach using a specialized function.
Have a look at this SO-question: [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

Comment: Thanks Thariama. +1 from me (here and on your linked answer).