# jquery, tinyMCE 2.1.3 - get content from the second instance

Tags: jquery, tinymce

This is how I initialized the tinyMCE plugin for two textareas in my webpage in php.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        //to add any new plugin add in this line
        plugins : "banglafkb,banglavkb,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,zoom,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "banglafkb,banglavkb",
        //theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "banglafkb,banglavkb",
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add : "fontselect, fontsizeselect ",
        //theme_advanced_buttons2_add_before: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,separator,search,replace,separator",
        //theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before : "tablecontrols,separator",
        //theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "emotions,iespell,media,advhr,separator,print,separator,ltr,rtl,separator,fullscreen",      
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",       
        content_css : "example_word.css",
            plugi2n_insertdate_dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d",
            plugi2n_insertdate_timeFormat : "%H:%M:%S",
        external_link_list_url : "example_link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "example_image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "example_media_list.js",
        file_browser_callback : "fileBrowserCallBack",
        paste_use_dialog : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
        theme_advanced_link_targets : "_something=My somthing;_something2=My somthing2;_something3=My somthing3;",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_convert_headers_to_strong : false,
        paste_strip_class_attributes : "all",
        paste_remove_spans : false,
        paste_remove_styles : false,    
        force_p_newlines:false,
        width:'700'
    });
```

By using `tinyMCE.getContent()` I get the content for the first editor instance but I need to get the content of the second editor instance too, how can I get that ?

Please NOTE that I am using the **2.1.3** version to  use plugins which were developed for that version only.

For further clarification:

The mentioned version is available [here](http://ekushey.org/projects/browser_ime/tinybn/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js). and [this](http://ekushey.org/projects/browser_ime/tinybn/) is the example of that version with plugins that were developed for that version and which I need to use. The 'select keyboard' dropdown shows the plugin in action.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my ...! This tinymce version is so old. Newer versions will work and handle issues with newer browsers, something this old version is not capable of. Well, what you want is possible:

Buy calling `tinyMCE.instances.mce_editor_0.getHTML()` you get the Content of the first editor instace. To get the content of the second editor instance you may use

```
tinyMCE.instances.mce_editor_1.getHTML()
```

**Update**: Looks like i got a working solution withoutthe use of jQuery:

```
var instance = tinyMCE.get('mce_editor_1'); // get the editor instance
instance.select(); // select your editor instance
tinyMCE.getContent() // get the content
```

Comment: oh so great.. 1) But did you get it from any documentation or by looking into the plugin itself ? 2) if I use banglafkb and banglavkb extensions for the latest version, that does not work. it would be really nice to use them in the latest one.

Comment: i found this out fiddling with the browser javascript variables under window

Comment: i found some docs, but they do not reveal much. you can access the editor content using  (with the help of jQuery): $(tinyMCE._getElementById('mce_editor_0')).contents().find('body').html(); Can you add the second editor to your example page?

Comment: Actually I followed the page. That is not developed by me. And why do you need the second example ? If you do need, I can upload it in my server.

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: Let me test the **Update** added later.

Comment: @: in case this answer really works you should accept it (plus upvote maybe)