# when i paste a word in tinymce editor in ie9 it goes into next line

Tags: internet-explorer-9, tinymce

Typing a word and copy it and paste it on the same line in tinymce editor in ie9,but the pasting is applies on the ext line.i want the word should be near and on the same line.
please give a solution

For example:
type 'test job'and copy paste it..then the result should be in
testjobtest job

but i got it as

```
<P>test job<p>
<p>test job</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are coping `<p>test job<p>` which will let the editor create a new paragraph.
Looks what you want is to get rid of unwanted tags.
For a solution to this task have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text/4122969#4122969).
You can define what happens with pasted content using the [paste_preprocess config setting](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste).

Comment: i had write the strip_tag function inpaste_preprocess config ,then it delete all the <p>tag.I only wants that certain instatnce only the extra <p>tag is coming

Comment: you can configure the strip_tags function to not strip out all tags, have a look at the comment above the function in order to find out how you can configure it