# How to disable formatted text in tinymce?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I have bounded tinyMCE to a textarea in my page,

How to disable formatted text entry in tinymce without unbinding tinyMCE from textarea?

Comment: can you give any more detail? do you mean when you copy and paste from word or some such word processing application you keep the formatting and want that to be removed?

Comment: e.g. when I press Ctrl+B the text becomes bold

Comment: If you dont want the text to be formatted why do you need to use tinyMCE?

Comment: Actually I am using it with spell checking plugin, http://www.polishmywriting.com/atd-tinymce/demo.html

Answer (score 3):

First, you can disable the buttons bold, italic, underline. Additionally you can remove the buttons for the plugins style.

Second, there is a way to remove formatted text when pasting:
[TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

Third, you may disable the drag&drop handling for the editor and hinder the user to get formatted text into the editor this way. Hava a look at the tinymce config param `paste_block_drop` under [paste](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste).

Comment: concerning shortcuts to apply formattings, you may overwrite those shortcut using the tinymce onKeyDown event and stop the propagation of events there