# How to allow HTML tags with TinyMCE paste plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

I was wondering that I couldn't find a solution to this problem, after searching several hours.

I want two modes in my almighty TinyMCE editor:

1. Allow to copy/paste HTML text or Word/OpenOffice text with most styles and formatting attributes
2. Enable by default the paste plug-in and remove most of the HTML, **but allow simple formatting**.

I am able to copy/paste HTML text or Word/OpenOffice text with most styles.
Also the paste plug-in button is enabled by default.

**However I am not sure how to configure the paste plug-in to allow some HTML Tags, particular lists (ol, ul, li), line breaks (br) and simple formatting (b, i, u), if the paste plug-in button was clicked.**

I tried to modify the `paste_postprocess` and `paste_preprocess` function, but did not find a solution. Also configuring `valid_elements` does not brought me success.

My settings (the important parts):

```
plugins : "paste,tabfocus,table,safari",
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
paste_create_paragraphs: false,
paste_create_linebreaks : false,
paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) { },
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) { },
paste_remove_spans:true,
paste_remove_styles:true,
paste_remove_styles_if_webkit:true,
paste_retain_style_properties:"none",
paste_strip_class_attributes:"all",
paste_text_sticky:true,
convert_urls : false,
entity_encoding : "raw",
valid_elements : "em/i,strong/b,ol,ul,li,br",
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
forced_root_block : false,
invalid_elements : "font",
setup : function(ed) {
  ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
    ed.pasteAsPlainText = true; // select "paste" on startup
  });
},
verify_html : false
```

Comment: My TinyMCE Version: 3.4.9. All Tests on Windows XP with Firefox 20.

Answer (score 3):

Using the paste config setting paste_preprocess you may filter the incoming content and only keep the tags you want to keep.
Have a closer look here: [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text/4122969#4122969)

Comment: Okay I will try again to edit paste_preprocess. But must I set paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste to false?

Comment: afaik, this doesn't matter (i have not changed the default which is true)