# remove the extra p tag in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

When you copy and paste from a word document in to the tinyMCE editor sometimes there are unwanted `<p>` tags:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="starpasspro-example-question">
   <p><strong>Example: Levels of strategy</strong></p>
   <p>Microsoft is one of the world&rsquo;s largest organisations, providing corporate solutions to businesses throughout the world to help them realise their fullest potential. At Microsoft, there are three levels of strategy as follows:</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Here  the code that generates I want to remove the `<p>` tags any way to do that ?

Comment: still not working for me. 
did you find a solution>?

Answer (score 17):

Add these Lines in your `tinymce.init({ });`

**Example:**

```
tinymce.init({
    forced_root_block : "", 
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

it will be helpful.

Add into your **tinymce.yml** file

```
forced_root_block : "" 

force_br_newlines : true

force_p_newlines : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. There is a secure way to remove all that html elements you want to removed (you may define what to keep). It is by using the tinymce config params `paste_preprocess` and a custom function `strip_tags`. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text/4122969#4122969).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file and the standard p-tags
tags will be removed by adding some parameters to the tiny_mce_before_init hook. If you want to see how it works, you can read further on this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////REMOVE STANDARD <P> FROM TINYMCE EDITOR/////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
$in['forced_root_block'] = "";
$in['force_br_newlines'] = TRUE;
$in['force_p_newlines'] = FALSE;
return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42157148/4174897) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

**USE HtmlEncode="false"  in BoundField**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PostContent" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prahalad Gaggar!

I had the same problem and I solved it by reading this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22397116/14491024

here is my code with each time adding   <p<br/<br/</p

so annoying)

function HTMLeditor( parameters) {

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');

tinymce.init({
    height: 500,
    selector: ".modal-body",
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons ', 
    image_advtab: true,

    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
            editor.setContent(parameters);
        });
    }

});
```

}

And here is with problem SOLVED:

function HTMLeditor( parameters) {

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');

tinymce.init({
    height: 500,
    selector: ".modal-body",
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons ', 
    image_advtab: true,

    //remove <p><br /><br /></p>
    forced_root_block: "" ,
    force_br_newlines: true,
    force_p_newlines: false,


    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
            editor.setContent(parameters);
        });
    }

});
```

}