# How can I remove p tags that are auto added within tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tinymce

I am using tinymce 4.0.1 and it automatically adds p tags when you either start typing or hit enter. How can I dynamically remove these p tags and then reinsert the content into the editor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tinymce needs a [root block element](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block), which is a paragraph by default, in order to be able to style content. So removing those paragraphs will only result in all content being wrapped into one single paragraph because tinymce is forced to use this as root block element.

Comment: i understand that, and that is the point of my project. I actually figured out how to do it though, thanks for the response.

Comment: for everyone else, this link is the correct answer to my problem

Comment: I tried using this but still get the P tag surrounding my text, any idea why?

Answer (score 58):

you need to add the following line to your init statement

```
forced_root_block : ""
```

So, your complete code will be like this:

```
    <script>tinymce.init({forced_root_block : "",selector:'textarea'});</script>
```

Comment: This setting has no effect. Not sure why people keep posting this as the answer!

Comment: @MC9000 For me it worked.. by default I was getting my content enclosed in <p> tag and after using the forced_root_block there is no <p> tag.

Comment: **Working fine** for me, I'm using the latest build (March 2021).

Comment: Important: Setting `forced_root_block` to false or an empty string has been deprecated in TinyMCE 5.10. For TinyMCE 6.0, this option will only accept valid block elements. [See more.](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block)

Answer (score 8):

You can remove "p" tag by adding `forced_root_block : false` to your tinymce setup or you can hide the status bar by `statusbar: false`

Comment: `forced_root_block` is expecting a String, not a Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Add this only in call javascript:

```
forced_root_block : false
```

Comment: This setting has no effect, at least not in the latest version.

Comment: Follow the documentation:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$("p").each(function(){$(this).parent().append($(this).html()); $(this).remove()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line to your init statement.

```
forced_root_block : ""
```

Comment: This setting has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply tweak what TinyMCE puts into the database *when you display it?*  See my post for the [same thing for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596205/how-to-prevent-the-p-tag-from-wrapping-around-my-input-with-tinymce-in-rails/).

```
var str = "{TinyMCE HTML string}"; /* however you get it */
str = str.replace(/^\<p\>/,"").replace(/\<\/p\>$/,"");
```

Here you are removing the beginning and ending p tag of the whole TinyMCE HTML *when you display it*.  Doesn't mess with other p tags or the TinyMCE config.

Explanation of the regex expression (removed \'s for ease of reading):

```
^<p> - find <p> at the start of the string (^) and replace it with nothing.
</p>$ - find </p> at the end of the string ($) and replace it with nothing.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good but there could be a difficulty, for example if there is more than one paragraph in the TinyMCE HTML string. In that case you might be better off using something like the following: `str = str.replace(/^<p>(?!.*<p[^>]*>)(.*)<\/p>$/i, "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

Insert in theme `functions.php` the following code:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_switch_tinymce_p_br'); 

function my_switch_tinymce_p_br($settings) {
    $settings['forced_root_block'] = false;
    return $settings;
}
```

If you want replace root "p" tag with some else, replace false with "div" (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file and the standard

tags will be removed by adding some parameters to the tiny_mce_before_init hook.
If you want to see how it works, you can read further on this page:
https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////REMOVE STANDARD <P> FROM TINYMCE EDITOR/////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
$in['forced_root_block'] = "";
$in['force_br_newlines'] = TRUE;
$in['force_p_newlines'] = FALSE;
return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
forced_root_block : '',
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide that using **elementpath** config.

Docs:https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#elementpath
Ref: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-docs/issues/1373#issuecomment-578710877

Answer (score -6):

If you use jQuery could do:

```
$("p").remove();
```

Comment: I realize that I can use this once I get the contents, but how do I put the contents back into the tinymce after.