# How to prevent the <p> tag from wrapping around my input with tinymce in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tinymce

By default, the tinymce input gets passed to the DOM as a paragraph tag:

I would like to remove that element wrapper so that tinymce passes exactly what I entered in the text editor.
How do I do that ? Please if you provide a code, can you also let me know where that code gets added ?
Regards !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I solved my problem. All I had to do was change the styling for paragraph  tag :

```
p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `forced_root_block` to false. However the documentation states that not having your root block as a `<p>` tag can cripple the editors behaviour. Newlines will be spaced with `<br>` tags instead.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    forced_root_block: false
});
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block)

Comment: Quiet old post, but I came accross it today. +1 for solving my issue. However, this solution only works with TinyMCE 3.x, the option is not supported at present in tinyMCE 4.X, see page [https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2634]. In addition, the presented code goes into your Javascript, after the tiny_mce.js file is loaded.

Comment: It's still supported according to their [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block)

Answer (score 0):

I strip out those pesky things with gsub and regex like this:

```
<%= @event.desc_long.gsub(/^\<p\>/,"").gsub(/\<\/p\>$/,"") %>
```

First .gsub removes the `<p>` at the start of the TinyMCE string, and the second one removes the `</p>` at the end.  Working great for me.  This would work for any language that uses regex (gsub is for rails).  JavaScript example:

```
var str = "{TinyMCE HTML string}"; 
str = str.replace(/^\<p\>/,"").replace(/\<\/p\>$/,"");
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Re: where to put it.  You leave what TinyMCE puts in your database alone.  Add the above only when you display it (in the view, e-mail whatever).

Comment: I would recommend avoiding this. The answer by PalinDrome555 seems much more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to get rid of margins:

```
tinymce.init({
...
setup: function(ed) { 
  ed.on('init', function() { 
    var doc = this.getDoc().getElementById("tinymce");
    doc.style.margin = 0;
  });
},
});
```