# How can I remove the p tag in tinymice editor on react js

Tags: reactjs

<Editor id="mytextarea" name="briefHistory" onInit={(event, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)} onChange={handleEditor} />

Comment: If <p> is part of <Editor> then you cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce needs [a root block element](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#forced_root_block), which is a paragraph by default, in order to be able to style content. So removing those paragraphs will only result in all content being wrapped into one single paragraph because tinymce is forced to use this as root block element.

```
<Editor id="mytextarea" name="briefHistory" onInit={(event, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)} onChange={handleEditor}  init={{forced_root_block: 'div'}}/>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401342/6784846

React Reference: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/

Comment: what would the implementation look like using my code above?

Comment: @Nnaemeka

`tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  forced_root_block: 'div'
});`

This might help you.

Comment: would this code be written inside the <Editor /> tag . Like this -
<Editor tinymce.init({   selector: '#mytextarea',   forced_root_block: 'div' }) />
 This is a react Js project by the way.

Comment: `<Editor id="mytextarea" name="briefHistory" onInit={(event, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)} onChange={handleEditor}  init={{forced_root_block: 'div'}}/>`