# How to remove the P tag from TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I work with TinyMCE and it surrounds my text with a `<p>` tag.

I tried using this: `forced_root_block : ""` following this: [How can I remove p tags that are auto added within tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376595/how-can-i-remove-p-tags-that-are-auto-added-within-tinymce)

and this isn't working for me :X

I saw this post too: 
[remove the extra p tag in tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058644/remove-the-extra-p-tag-in-tinymce)

and added:

```
forced_root_block : "", 
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false
```

and this isn't helping.

This is my current code part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".mytextarea", 
        plugins: "paste",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_remove_styles: true,
        paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
        paste_strip_class_attributes: "all", 
        forced_root_block : "", 
        force_br_newlines : true, // tried with and without
        force_p_newlines : false // tried with and without
        //paste_remove_spans : true
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the following line to your init statement

```
forced_root_block :false


<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".mytextarea", 
        plugins: "paste",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_remove_styles: true,
        paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
        paste_strip_class_attributes: "all", 
        forced_root_block : false, 
        force_br_newlines : true, // tried with and without
        force_p_newlines : false // tried with and without
        //paste_remove_spans : true
    });
</script>
```

if this not work than try  change in "tiny_mce.js" and not in "tiny_mce_src.js"

Comment: It's already there, So the order is important? it has to be on the top? :S